# Using other types of controllers with windows store apps and games which only support Xbox controller

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app, game-controller

As I know there is a way to virtually convert almost any type of controller to an Xbox 360 controller by using this software: [x360ce](http://www.x360ce.com/default.aspx)
As in it's website is stated I should copy and past all the x360ce files into the games root directory and it really works with almost every game.
now I wanna use my controllers with "windows store" games but I don't know where to put those x360ce files.
does anyone know how to do this for windows store games?

PS. I'm using windows 10 x64 Professional Edition

Answer (score 2):

As of the time I'm writing this, there is no way to modify or copy files to the Windows Apps folder. Windows Store Apps are all installed on `C:/Program Files/WindowsApps`. This location can be changed through the settings app, but it doesn't change the fact that windows will not even let you see the contents of the folder. You can bypass that by taking Ownership of the folder, which will grant you viewing privileges, but you will not be able still to copy anything to the folder.

I've have the exact same issue. I've tried lots of things. As it stands the security for that folder is rock solid. The is a `TrustedUser` account on Windows 10 which is the only one who can launch or modify anything inside the `WindowsApps` folder. However, those privileges are not transferable, nor can you log into windows with that account. Furthermore, the Folder is encrypted with a public-private key encryption, and the private key is only available to the `TrustedUser` account, which means not even if you boot into Linux are you able to modify the files. (Which I've tried)

I learned all of this a couple of weeks ago while trying to use `x360ce` with `Forza Motorsport 6 Apex`.

**EDIT**

You CAN use Inputmapper 2 with some plugins to convert any DInput Controller to an XInput one, no need to copy any files to the games directory

Answer (score 0):

xpadder is not a good solution as it maps keyboard/mouse to controller.
it lacks the sensitivity of the controller.
most games today are adapted to controller ans simply remapping keys will not do the trick.
take e.g. the aim assist with helps you lock onto targets with a controller.
this will not work with xpadder. you will have a controller which "thinks" it is a mouse for aiming.